# Why is it not possible to delete appointments in Exchange

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm setting up a two way synchronization service for Appointments between Exchange and another business application. Because there was an old service before mine, I want to delete all the old appointments in Exchange but this is not possible with all appointments.

Everytime I debug, the appointments I can delete have `appointment.Organizer.RoutingType` filled with "SMTP" and `appointment.Organizer.Address` is filled with the e-Mail Address. The other ones have `appointment.Organizer.RoutingType` filled with "EX" and `appointment.Organizer.Address`with something like that:
    /O=HOSTING/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP FYDIBOHF23SYZLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=E373428996

```
do
{
    itemChangeCollection = service.SyncFolderItems(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar), propertySet, null, 512, SyncFolderItemsScope.NormalItems, syncState);
    foreach (ItemChange itemChange in itemChangeCollection)
    {
        try
        {
            if (itemChange.ChangeType != ChangeType.Delete)
            {
                Appointment app = Appointment.Bind(service, itemChange.ItemId, propertySet);
                app.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    syncState = itemChangeCollection.SyncState;
} while (itemChangeCollection.MoreChangesAvailable);
```

The error which is coming in the delete line is the following
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 'The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account.'

The problem is not only the not possible delete, but also I need the E-Mail address of the organizer in my sync logic. Anybody here who knows why sometimes there is SMTP and sometimes EX?

Answer (score 0):

EWS is attempting to send meeting cancellations for the specified appointment first and apparently the account you are using is not allowed to send on behalf of that mailbox. Try to cancel the meetign first: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-delete-appointments-and-cancel-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: When I do this, I get the following error:
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 'The user account which was used to submit this request does not have the right to send mail on behalf of the specified sending account.'

Comment: Or you can just give the service account the send-as right on behalf of the mailbox in question.

Comment: Or if you don't want to send cancellations then you can just specify a `sendCancellationsMode` parameter of `SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone`.